# Reducibility of $x^4+1$ in prime fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Dummit and Foote's "Abstract Algebra" there is a proof for the reducibility of $x^4+1$ in which it's stated:

> For odd primes p, $p^2\equiv1\pmod 8$. Hence $x^8-1\mid x^{p^2-1}-1 $.

Why does $x^8-1\mid x^{p^2-1}-1$ follow?

Comment: Note that this property (irreducible over the integers but reducible mod every prime) happens if and only if you take a degree $n$ irreducible polynomial whose Galois group has no elements of order $n$ (the Galois group of $x^4+1$ has only elements of order 1 and 2, but you can easily construct other examples (e.g. just take a polynomial with group $A_4$)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if $p^2\equiv 1 $ (mod $8$) then $p^2-1=8k$ for some $k$, so
$$x^{8k}-1=(x^8-1)(1+x^8+\cdots+x^{8(k-1)})$$

as you can easily can verify.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that, if $n > 0$, then $a^n - b^n = (a-b) P(a,b)$, where $P(a,b) = \sum_{k=0} ^{n-1} a^{n-1 - k} b^k$.

Since there exist $k \in \Bbb Z$ such that $p^2 = 1 + 8k$ (it is easy to see that $k > 0$), it follows that

$$x^{p^2-1} - 1 = x^{8k} - 1 = (x^8)^k - 1^k = (x^8-1) Q(x) ,$$

where I have used the formula in the first paragraph with $a=x^8$, $b=1$, $n=k$ and $P(a,b) = Q(x)$. It follows then that $x^8 - 1 \mid x^{p^2-1} - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

As a side answer, not to the original question, you can get this result fairly explicitly.

If $-1=a^2$, for some $a$, then $x^4+1=(x^2+a)(x^2-a)$.

If $2=a^2$ for some $a$, then $x^4+1=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2-ax+1)$.

If $-2=a^2$ for some $a$, then $x^4+1=(x^2+ax-1)(x^2-ax-1)$.

But if $-1$ and $2$ are not squares, modulo $p$, then $-2$ is a a square, modulo $p$.